# R 32bit function write.csv does not import nordic characters correctly

Tags: r, csv

I am using R32bit to access a 32bit ODBC database. Some of the columns contain nordic characters "å", "ø" and "æ". Upon viewing this data in R through for example View(data), these characters appear as a question mark.

I need to export this data to a csv file that I later import into PowerBI for reporting and online collaboration using PowerBI Repport Server.

If I use R32bit, these values are converted when using write.csv as strange characters between brackets <>. On the other hand, when using R64bit, these characters are converted correctly to the csv file.

I have tried write_excel_csv rom the readr library, but I obtain other wrong characters when using R32bit.

Is there a way you can suggest where I do not need to switch from R32bit to R64bit in order to both access teh 32bit ODBC database and export the data to a csv format correctly?

Comment: What is "R32bit" exactly?  What version is it?  Where did you get it?  What platform are you working on?

Comment: I am working with Rstudio 2022.02.1 Build 461, R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) -- "Action of the Toes", Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

Comment: Upgrade to R 4.2.1 for [unicode support](https://blog.r-project.org/2022/06/16/upcoming-changes-in-r-4.2.1-on-windows/). This will probably fix the issue.

Comment: Upgrading is probably the best solution, but there's no 32 bit R 4.2.1 on Windows.

Comment: @SamR thanks for the advice, in fact this is the process I currently follow, but it requires me to change from a 32bit R for downloading the info, and then using a 64bir R for creating the csv files, and using an RData object to communicate between the R32bit and R64bit. My particular predicament is that I need to access a 32bit database. I assume this is not possible for a R64 bit version.